# Maven rewrite filter for Primefaces CSS Theme generated with ThemeRoller

Tags: java, maven, primefaces, themeroller

I'm creating custom themes for PrimeFaces with ThemRoller. Each theme is related to a single maven artifact and the jar is created perfectly with the `maven-resources-plugin`.

The theme is generated with URLs like this:

```
url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard.png")
```

To be used in a jar, the url must be rewrittten into this format:

```
url("#{resource['primefaces-yourtheme:images/ui-bg_highlight-hard.png']}")
```

To directly see the theme (and modify it), it would be nicer to keep the css in the format without `#{}` in the `src/main/resources` folder. Is there a way to apply a maven filter to automatically rewrite the urls?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [maven-replacer-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/).

You should be able to use a regex to insert the JSF resource loading EL.